# jQuery mutual logic of the script (the subject input is getting locked)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple script: it reads the value of `quantity` input and if it's greater than 5, jQuery will automatically select radio button #2. If the value of `quantity` is lesser than 5, it will select radio button #1.

Now my problem is that **this script makes radio buttons unclickable**, because their state is strictly tied to the script. But I would like it if clicking on radio button #2 would change value of the input to 5 and click on the radio button #1 would change it to 1.

In other words, I would like this script to work both ways and to not lock my buttons.

```js
$('.mycontainer').on('click', function() {

if (parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10) >= '5') {
    $('#2radio').prop('checked', true);
}
 else {
 $('#1radio').prop('checked', true);
}
}).click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mycontainer">

  <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"><br><br>
  
    <input type="radio" id="1radio" name="radio"><label for="1radio">radio button #1</label><br><br>
    <input type="radio" id="2radio" name="radio"><label for="2radio">radio button #2</label>
    
    <div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you check a `radio`, the event is [bubbling up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture) and triggering the `.mycontainer` function, and since the value isn't changed, it reselects the other radio. 
You just have to implement the new handlers for the `radio`s. Since they will change the input `number`, when the function triggers the radio that the condition would select will be already selected.

If you want to prevent the event from bubbling and trigger the other function altoghether you can call [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Another option is to target `#quantity` directly instead of `.mycontainer`, and the function won't fire, since it's a sibling and not an ancestor element.

```js
$('.mycontainer').on('click', function() {
  if (parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10) >= '5') {
    $('#2radio').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('#1radio').prop('checked', true);
  }
})

$('[type=radio]').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#quantity').val($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mycontainer">
  <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"><br><br>
  <input type="radio" id="1radio" name="radio" value="1"><label for="1radio">radio button #1</label><br><br>
  <input type="radio" id="2radio" name="radio" value="5"><label for="2radio">radio button #2</label>
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to implement it right now. By the way, I have also noticed if I `attr` checked instread of `prop` checked, it does not lock my buttons. Would it be a preferred way?